# How to stop the error of "fielref is still in use"

Tags: sql, macros, sas

I have this webcrawl code, that gets certain information from a website source code. it runs a macro, then calls 2 more macros. When accessing those macros after the first time, an error occurs. "At least one file associated with filref is still in use" 
Below is sample code that it runs. Let me know if something needs to be more clear.

```
%macro webcrawl(search_url);
    %let url3 =  &search_url;
    filename _next3 url  "&url3";

    data search_website;
        infile _next3 length = len lrecl = 32767;
        input text $varying32767. len;
        if index(text,'<header>') or index(text, '<p>');
    run;

    proc sql;
        create table table1 as
        select distinct var1
        from table;
    quit;


    /* Calls the macro from above to "crawl" the website 
    %do i=1 %to &show_count;
        %showpage1( &i, &&var_&i, http://www.website.com );
        %showpage2( &i, &&var_&i, http://www.website.com/2 );
    %end;
```

The below is code for showpage1, it is the same for showpage2, just different website.

```
%macro showpage1( index, show, url );
    %let url1 = &url;
    filename _next url "&url";

    data search_website;
        infile _next length = len lrecl = 32767;
        input text $varying32767. len;    
        if index(text, '<span>') or index(text, '</span>');
        retain i;    
        if index(text, '<h2 class="title"') then i+1;
    run;

    data counting;
        set search_website;
        by i;    
        if first.i then count = 0;
        count+1;
    run;

    proc transpose data=counting out=search_one_line prefix=info;
        by i;
        id count;
        var text;
    run;

    data info1_&i (keep=var1 var 2 var3);
        set dataset1;
    run;

    options missing=0;

%mend showpage1;
```

Comment: There is a weird comment above the last %let. And I don't know, but you're missing a run statement below the if.

Comment: Not the full code. When it tries to access the %do loop, there is where the error occurs. I need to close, delete, stop, the fileref each time.

Comment: So is it code in %showpage1 and/or %showpage2  that is throwing the error?  If so, what do those macros look like?

Comment: Added the showpage info. Thanks for all your quick responses.

Comment: Have you tried putting `filename _next clear;` at the end of `%showpage`?  That might fix the problem.

Comment: I did try that, I also tried filename _all_ clear. I have also tried deleting the macro from the dictionary file to no avail.

Comment: I think the error means the web page is still active/connected/open.  Not sure exactly why that would occur here.  Does it go away if you wait a few minutes?

Comment: So it's the filename statement that throws the error?  On the second iteration of the loop when it's trying to reassign _next?  When you tried filename _next clear did that throw the same error on the first iteration? If so, then I agree with Joe.  And seems odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to figure out why SAS thinks the file is still in use, but there are a couple of ways you could modify your program that might make the problem go away.

You could use a different fileref each time the macro runs. You can use the `SYSINDEX` automatic variable for this since it counts the number of macro calls.

```
filename _n&sysindex url "&url";
...
infile _n&sysindex length = len lrecl = 32767;
```

Also make sure to clear the fileref after the data step finishes.

```
...
run;
filename _n&sysindex clear ;
```